# What is the interference pattern?

Tags: interference

[image: Three parallel rays with differing path lengths]

Imagine three coherent monochromatic waves as depicted in the image. Say we are interested in the interference at a very distant point P (not depicted). As one can see, B will interfere destructively with A and C whereas A and C will interfere constructively with each other. My question is: what intensity will we see at P? Will there be brightness, darkness or something in between? My guess is that we will see the constructive interference between A and C. On the other hand, one might not see anything because B has cancelled both A and C, so they can't even interfere with each other? What is it going to be?

Comment: As posed, your question cannot be answered.  The green lines presumably represent rays, while the dotted lines presumably represent wavefronts.  No aperture width is specified, and the location of P relative to the aperture is specified.  You should look up single-slit diffraction and Fraunhofer diffraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the amplitude of the waves from each of the sources at the observation position be $A$.

If there is no difference in path then the resultant amplitude at the observation position is $A+A+A=3A$ and the intensity of this zero order fringe is $9A^2$.

If the path difference between adjacent sources is $\frac{\lambda}{3}$ then the resultant amplitude is zero.

$A\sin(\omega t)+A\sin(\omega t+\frac{2π}{3})+A\sin(\omega t+ \frac{4π}{3}) =0$.

For the $\frac{\lambda}{2}$ path difference that you asked about the resultant amplitude is $A-A+A=A$ with an intensity $A^2$.

$A\sin(\omega t) +A\sin(\omega t+\pi)+A\sin(\omega t+ 2\pi) = A\sin(\omega t) $.

—-

This [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/253566/104696) has much more detail about multiple source interference (including three source) and information as to how you could use phasors to predict what the interference pattern might look like.