# Interference using three slits

Tags: optics, double-slit-experiment, interference

Lets say there is a Young double slit interference apparatus, but with three slits placed at $y= - d$, $0$, $d$, and where the screen is at $X = D$ parallel to the $y$ axis. Can there be any areas on the screen where the intensity is at a minimum? If yes, then which points will be those, and how can I mathematically find those points?

Comment: Related? [Fringe width and spacing and number of slits in diffraction experiments](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/203367/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fringe width and spacing and number of slits in diffraction experiments](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/203367/)

Comment: But I am not able to find solution to a numerical problem even after using the formula for resultant amplitude due to three slits.

Answer (score 1):

If $D$ is sufficiently large you can suppose the first and second have the phase differencw $\phi$, and the first and the second have phase difference $2\phi$.
Then you have 
$$\sin(\omega t)+\sin(\omega t+\phi)+\sin(\omega t+2\phi)=\sin(\omega t)+\sin(\omega t) \cos\phi)+\cos(\omega t) \sin(\phi)+\sin(\omega t)+\cos(2\phi)+\cos(\omega t)*\sin(2\phi)$$
so $$1+\cos(\phi)+\cos(2\phi)=0$$  and  $$\sin(\phi)+\sin(2\phi)=0$$
Let Wolfram do the calculating.